# Exibir dados do nodeJS no front-end usando express sem usar framework front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, front-end, back-end

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de passar dados manipulados no back-end em nodeJS para um arquivo html sem usar framemework front-end. Nas minhas pesquisas achei exemplos usando jquery.

Comment: Sua pergunta está pouco clara... Por favor, edite-a adicionando um pouco mais de informações. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de passar dados do node para o seu frontend seria utilizar EJS. O EJS utiliza arquivos HTML com a extensão EJS, e dentro deles, você pode enviar ou receber dados de suas rotas definidas no seu projeto Express/Node.

Para instalar, como você já tem o Express instalado, você pode fazer assim:

```
npm install ejs express-ejs-layouts --save
```

Aqui tem um exemplo de como ficaria uma rota (GET):

```js
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  var users = [{
    name: faker.name.findName(),
    email: faker.internet.email(),
    avatar: 'http://placekitten.com/300/300'
  }, {
    name: faker.name.findName(),
    email: faker.internet.email(),
    avatar: 'http://placekitten.com/400/300'
  }, {
    name: faker.name.findName(),
    email: faker.internet.email(),
    avatar: 'http://placekitten.com/500/300'
  }]

  res.render('pages/about', { usuarios: users })
})
```

Neste exemplo, o array "user" é enviado para um arquivo localizado em "pages/about.ejs". Para este arquivo, é enviada uma variável chamada "usuarios".

Dentro de  "pages/about.ejs", este array é exibido da seguinte forma:

```html
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
     <h1>O Time!</h1>
     <div class="row">
      <% for (usuario of usuarios){%>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <h2><%= usuario.name %>
         <img class="img-responsive" style="height: 250px" src="<%= usuario.avatar %>">
        </div>
      <% } %>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Aqui tem um passo a passo, mostrando como criar um layout utilizando EJS

http://tsdn.tecnospeed.com.br/blog-da-consultoria-tecnica-tecnospeed/post/utilizando-a-engine-ejs-para-aplicacoes-em-nodejs